# Video replacing slides html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a video background with words written over it like this site:

https://animoto.com/

I know it's CSS but I can't seem to get it:

```
video#bgvid { 
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -100;
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
background-size: cover;

}
```

This is the CSS I used, but it makes the whole background video, and I just want it like animoto.com.

Comment: By tagging with `java`, do you really mean `java`, or do you mean `javascript`?

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet.

Comment: i meant javascript @LGson

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all I figured it out... had to make the video fluid by setting its width to 100%